# User Control DirectShow VMR9 Video Display Freezes when unlock computer

Tags: c#, user-controls, directshow, directshow.net

I have a custom User Control in a WinForm which I am using to display streamed video using VMR9/DirectShow.Net. I feed decoded frames into a custom PushSource filter. I see strange behaviour when the computer is locked then unlocked

1. If I do this fairly quickly then the video will start playing as soon as I unlock the computer.
2. Sometimes there is a delay of 5 – 60 seconds before the video starts displaying again
3. Sometime the video display never recovers.

I should also add that I can record the video using FFMpeg while the computer is locked and also have confirmed that the frames are being inserted into the source filter but are not being displayed (following an unlock)

I have added a thread using IMediaEvent to monitor graph events. When I start my streaming/graph I see events ClockChanged and Paused (even though it is playing). When I unlock my computer I see event VMRRenderDeviceSet param1 = 2, param2 = 0 and Paused (param1 = 0, param2 = 0).

My Graph topology is (Custom) Push Source Filter -> Color Space Converter -> Ds .Net Grabber - > Color Space Converter 0001 -> Video Mixing Renderer 9.

Also I can grab the correct frame while the display is frozen so it seems to be the problem is the VMR9.

With the information provided can anyone shed some light on what could be wrong? I can provide any other details as required.

Comment: Deadlocks at workstation unlock are typically caused by SystemEvents firing an event on the wrong thread.  This goes back to the initialization of your program, what thread creates the first window matters.  With trouble when it isn't the main thread.  Writing your own splash screen is the typical cause.

Comment: The main thread creates the form which inturn creates the control. There is no splash screen or anything like that. As far I could see there are no SystemEvents for unlock, only session ending/ended and session switch. Do you think I need to handle these events in some way?

Comment: No, I just mentioned it as a common reason.  There's too little info your question to help weed out possibilities like this.  The odds you'll get a helpful answer are low.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the windows7 predefined codecs then replace them with something like xvid, in win7 I had the same problem while lost the 3d device, it may be caused by using ctrl+alt+del or something like that.

Please check this link:
http://www.codecguide.com/windows7_preferred_filter_tweaker.htm

After configurations just run the graphstudio and drag an avi file in it so you will see which codecs the system use. You will see the same behavior in graphedit with default win7 codes after ctrl+alt+del.

But actually is some problem with reset device handling by the default win7 codecs.

Comment: How would I replace the codecs, just install them or do I need to force there use when creating the graph? Ctrl+Alt+Del gives me a similar behaviour and there seems to be more info on this on the net so hopefully I find something.

Comment: Install the klite codec pack it contains a special tool to replace the win7 codecs or just google how.

Comment: Been away for a few days so just got round to trying this. I should have mentioned before but the lock issue occured when playing back video too in the same application with a slightly different graph configuration. 
I installed K-Lite and disabled Mpeg4s Decoder DMO and ffshow video filter, this forced the graph to use AVI Decompressor as the decoder. On doing so I no longer see issues with locked/Ctl+Alt+Delete when playing videos. Unfortunaltley I still see the issue with my live video stream. I think the issue must be in my source filter so I am going to start digging around there.

Comment: Yes it could be a source filter, check how the events are processed through your graph, while the device is reseting, and if you handle them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is the error:

> // // MessageId: VFW_E_BUFFER_NOTSET // // MessageText: // // No
>   buffer space has been set.%0 //
>   define **VFW_E_BUFFER_NOTSET**              ((HRESULT)0x8004020CL)

There should be a cause for this error code, and it's unlikely VMR itself. Perhaps an upstream filter (what is the topology?) is stumbling on this error. And perhaps you can see other events generated by the graph, which you can receive and handle.

Answer (score 0):

I have same type of issue while working with custom allocator. The reason for this when we lock the computer then DirectX device will lost and all drawing will stop. if this is the case try to reset you device using device.reset method. 
[Here](https://sites.google.com/site/craigandera/craigs-stuff/directx-home/managed-direct3d-tutorial/13-device-recovery) is the sample to recover. Hope this help for you.